# Creating a webpage and want to call external links into html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a personal website which has all information and i have three webpages.
1.HTML page for front end 
2. CSS script for proper display of objects in HTML
3. JS script for manipulation and animation.

In CSS and JS i am calling two external links like gsapp/animate_form.css which is in build in editor but i want call the link from script.

Comment: We need some sort of an example of what you've tried to do so far, or a part of your code that makes your question easier to understand and solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gsapp/animate_form.css">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
   <link id="link" />
</head>
```

javascript

trigger statement on function

```
  <script>
//your function
    document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");

</script>
```